# R: Inserting data to existing SQL Database. Randomly omitting data?

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I try to insert data from R into a SQL Table. To this end I wrote the following function that creates the INSERT statement:

```
    CreateInsert <- function(Dataframe, TableName){
  Output=character()

  ColumnNames="("
  Values=colnames(Dataframe)
  for (i in 1:ncol(Dataframe)) {
    ColumnNames=paste(ColumnNames, Values[i], ",",sep="")
  }

  ColumnNames=substr(ColumnNames, 1, nchar(ColumnNames)-1)
  ColumnNames=paste(ColumnNames, ")",sep="")

  TableEtc=paste("INSERT INTO", TableName, ColumnNames)
  do.call("sprintf", c(paste(TableEtc, "VALUES  ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');"), Dataframe))

}
```

Subsequently I execute this statement after a quick check for NA:

```
  InsertQuery=CreateInsert(SelData, "TableName")
  InsertQuery=gsub("'NA'", "NULL", InsertQuery) # Regular Expression
  sqlQuery(DBconn, paste(InsertQuery, sep="", collapse=""))
```

However, it randomly omits rows. For instance I am storing a correlation matrix (melted into a long matrix). I am 100% sure the data is complete but when storing it and querying the results randomly some points are missing. Any idea why that occurs? The bigger the amount of insert rows, the more likely it occurs. Although hit even happens when I insert a single row thousands of times (looping).

FYI: I also tried to use sqlSave

```
sqlSave(DBconn, SelData, tablename='TABLENAME', append=TRUE, rownames=FALSE, safer=TRUE)
```

But this just gives me the error "unable to append to table" and I am less inclined to use it since it can also create a table if one would accidentally mistype. Creating tables I would not like to be performed by a user in R.

Thank you!

Comment: try using `verbose=TRUE` with sqlSave

Comment: Thanks! That indeed explains sqlSave: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'CorrelationTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. Problem with an auto_increment field, of which I read answers could be filled with NA (which then would be skipped), which I did but apparently that did not work!

Answer (score 0):

While that was driving me crazy the entire day... I think I have found the solution. The problem seem to lie with scientific notation. So I am using:

```
options(scipen=999)
```

(Setting it to 0 would put it back to default)

Apologies!